# Export Data Teradata Express

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I recently had to switch over from Teradata SQL Assistant to Teradata Express and it comes with its challenges. One being exporting data...I need to export to a .txt file tab delimited while maintaining the variable length.

Each and every way I try to export I keep getting the trailing space from my CHAR(30) and CHAR(50) trimmed off. I need that extra length to remain but it seems to be trimmed off on export. I did not have this issue running the same code from SQL Assistant when I had it.

--Export Wizard is clicked on then I run the below to bring up export prompt which I select TAB Delimited, UTF-8, and NONE for Char String Delim

```
SELECT
CAST(CARD AS CHAR(16)) AS CARD
,CAST(CARD_NAME AS CHAR(30)) AS CARD_NAME
,CAST(CUST_NAME AS CHAR(50)) AS CUST_NAME
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Currently in Studio you can either have fixed-width columns or have column delimiters added, but not both. Possible workaround would be something like `CAST(CHR(9)||CARD_NAME AS CHAR(31)) AS CARD_NAME` and export as fixed width.